# iMacros code working in IE, not in FF

Tags: firefox-addon, imacros

Following is the code that pastes clipboard contents in a textbox of a rich text editor called [Cute Editor](http://cutesoft.net/asp/EnableAll.asp)

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:aspnetForm ATTR=NAME:ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$fullarticles CONTENT="{{!CLIPBOARD}}"
```

While it works fine in IE, it does not work in FF. Looking for some help on what's wrong here with FF and how FF can accept it too?